# How to use GLPK library on Android

Tags: android, shared-libraries, linear-programming

I have a linear programming problem that I have to solve in an android application. I used [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math//) for solving it, but it turned out that this gives me the result in `double` values. I need to get the results in `integer` values.

After some search it turned out that **GLPK** library can be used for **MILP** (Mixed Integer Linear Programming), but it's Java implementation has a shared library that I can't use on an android device.

**Is there some possibility to use this library on an android device?** Or maybe some other library that can be used for MILP problems onan android device?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the JavaScript port of GLPK, called [GLPK.js](https://github.com/hgourvest/glpk.js), can be of use here? It runs completely in the browser and can handle MI(L)P problems. A very good [demo application](http://www3.nd.edu/~jeff/mathprog/mathprog.html) is available as well, including many examples to standard problems.

Comment: I need Java (Android) version, not JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long shot, but have you considered building application using **C#** and [**Mono Framework**](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid)? There is a C# wrapper for GLPK [here](http://yoyovicks.blog.free.fr/). I have to mention that I haven't used it. Other good open source MILP solver is LP Solve (lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/). This solver has both Java and C# wrappers.